# Alternative to lsof - to detect locked file

Tags: lsof

A file is locked with either a fcntl (non-blocking) or some custom way. So I'm using lsof and checking if pid of a process is in there. If lsof returns blank than nothing is using it.

However lsof from my script takes 200ms.

On windows when i try to test for if the file is locked i just open the file and on error its locked, this takes 5ms. Is there any alternative to lsof to do a quick test to see if something is got a hold of a file?

Comment: Thanks mans ill check that out and report back on speed :)

Comment: I added it as an answer, let me know if it solved ur issue.

Comment: `lsof` by default tries to resolve host names. `lsof -n` does not and is much faster.

Comment: Thanks very much @StéphaneGourichon!! So I should use `lsof -n FILE` correct? to find open files?

Comment: @Noitidart My comment was only about the usual reason why `lsof` is slow in general. In any case, you should include in your question the command line where you used `lsof`. I just tried `touch /tmp/locked ; flock /tmp/locked -c "sleep 120"` in a terminal and `time lsof -F cl /tmp/locked` in another. Time reported is 0.074s. `-F cl` asks to output command name and lock status in a way that is somehow easier to parse from a caller script.

Comment: If your lock times are shorter (you mention 30ms below), you should probably give up scripts and make a simple C program, or reconsider the whole point (perhaps http://xyproblem.info/ is relevant here).

Comment: Thanks @StéphaneGourichon - my use case was to find what PID is locking a certain file.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The fuser command is a very smart unix utility used to find which process is using a file, a directory or a socket. It also gives information about the user owning the process and the type of access. [READ MORE --digitalocean.com](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-the-linux-fuser-command)

To show processes accessing a particular directory use :

```
fuser -uvm /somedir
```

The below  output shows that, when ran in verbose mode, the fuse utility gives information about the `USER, PID, ACCESS and COMMAND`

```
root@exampleuser-X55CR:~# fuser -v .
                     USER        PID ACCESS COMMAND
/root:               root       3378 ..c.. vim
                     root       3398 ..c.. bash
                     root       3449 ..c.. bash
                     root      19370 ..c.. bash
```

`fuser` is useful in identifying process id opening a particular file.

`lsof` is useful to find out all file(s) opened by particular process.

for more options that go with fuser you can check thier man page `man fuser`

here is some :

```
]$ fuser
No process specification given
Usage: fuser [ -a | -s | -c ] [ -n SPACE ] [ -SIGNAL ] [ -kimuv ] NAME...
             [ - ] [ -n SPACE ] [ -SIGNAL ] [ -kimuv ] NAME...
       fuser -l
       fuser -V
Show which processes use the named files, sockets, or filesystems.

    -a        display unused files too
    -c        mounted FS
    -f        silently ignored (for POSIX compatibility)
    -i        ask before killing (ignored without -k)
    -k        kill processes accessing the named file
    -l        list available signal names
    -m        show all processes using the named filesystems
    -n SPACE  search in this name space (file, udp, or tcp)
    -s        silent operation
    -SIGNAL   send this signal instead of SIGKILL
    -u        display user IDs
    -v        verbose output
    -V        display version information
    -4        search IPv4 sockets only
    -6        search IPv6 sockets only
    -         reset options

  udp/tcp names: [local_port][,[rmt_host][,[rmt_port]]]
```

Comment: This was great it brought down the speed by 50ms compared to `lsof`!. However is there anything faster? Its still taking over 100ms and the functiosn that rely on this are happening within 30ms.

Comment: Also out of curiousity is there any flag that will make fuser print the process name like lsof. Lsof gives a bunch of other crap i just need pid and process name :) The -v didnt work :(

Comment: did you use it like this "fuser -v ."

Comment: yes sir it, but it still didnt resemble the output of ps. i did `fuser -v "/home/noi/Desktop/rawr.txt"` its no big. i was wondering if u can maybe also add to post something that can just see if something would have a pid using it, but not really bother about searching for any info and just return. i accepted answer though. im trying to get to 5ms on avg time. im thinking the fecthing of so much other data is leading to the 150ms maximum times.

Comment: I've trouble with piping `fuser` output to other commands like grep. It does not seem to use stdout normally.

Answer (score 0):

To find all pids of processes that are using a file
run this shell function that inspects the /proc directory

```
#!/bin/bash

set -o pipefail
shopt -s extglob

_lsof() {
   local f="${1}" \
       inum
   inum="$(ls -i "$(readlink -f "${f}")" 2> /dev/null )" && \
   ( find /proc/+([0-9])/fd -follow -inum ${inum%% *} 2> /dev/null || : ) | \
       cut -f 3 -s -d '/' | \
       sort -n -u | \
       grep -sxvF "1"
}

pids="$(_lsof "filename")" || \
  echo "file is not in use"
```